# openSuse, linux, chmod to change link's permisions

Tags: linux, opensuse, command-history

I am trying to change the permissions for the link.
I want the "Other" entity to have only the read permission, but when I run the command the permissions are not changing.
Is there something I am not doing correctly, or there is a different way to change the permissions for the links.

```
linux-gn77:~ # ls -l /usr/bin/startup.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root dev 31 May  3 20:33 /usr/bin/startup.sh -> /usr/lib   /tomcat7/bin/startup.sh
linux-gn77:~ # chmod 770 /usr/bin/startup.sh
linux-gn77:~ # ls -l /usr/bin/startup.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root dev 31 May  3 20:33 /usr/bin/startup.sh -> /usr/lib/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh
linux-gn77:~ # chmod o=r /usr/bin/startup.sh
linux-gn77:~ # ls -l /usr/bin/startup.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root dev 31 May  3 20:33 /usr/bin/startup.sh -> /usr/lib/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh
linux-gn77:~ # chmod o-r /usr/bin/startup.sh
linux-gn77:~ # ls -l /usr/bin/startup.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root dev 31 May  3 20:33 /usr/bin/startup.sh -> /usr/lib/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh
```

Please, let me know how can this be achieved.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the permissions for the link. You will need to change the permissions of the target instead. This is documented in `man 2 symlink`:

```
   The permissions of a symbolic link are  irrelevant;  the  ownership  is
   ignored  when following the link, but is checked when removal or renam‐
   ing of the link is requested and the link is in a  directory  with  the
   sticky bit (S_ISVTX) set.
```

So, to achieve what you want, you would need to run

```
 chmod 770 /usr/lib/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh
```